# How run package Depix?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I want to run the Duplex tool (https://github.com/beurtschipper/Depix ). But the test version does not start, when I type an in the command line:

```
python depix.py -p images/testimages/testimage3_pixels.png -s images/searchimages/debruinseq_notepad_Windows10_closeAndSpaced.png -o output.png
```

an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Work\Projects\Python\Depix\Depix-main\depixlib\depix.py ", line 10, in <module>
from. import __version__
Error Importer error: an attempt at relative import without a known parent package
```

In the READMI written

```
sh
depix \
    -p /path/to/your/input/image.png \
    -s images/searchimages/debruinseq_notepad_Windows10_closeAndSpaced.png \
    -o /path/to/your/output.png
```

But I do not know how to run it, please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it looks like it is a directory structure problem.
You can fix it by adding depixlib where you import the modules.

**depixlib\depix.py**

```
from depixlib import __version__
from depixlib.functions import
from depixlib.LoadedImage import LoadedImage
from depixlib.Rectangle import Rectangle
```

Hope it fixed your problem!

---

Now, I get the following errors, but that's another story.

**LoadedImage.py**

```
return cast(list[list[tuple[int, int, int]]], _imageData)
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

*edit:* Actually I fixed the above by changing the following line to:

Last line of **LoadedImage.py** file

```
return cast(list(list([int, int, int])), _imageData)
```

It was mentionned here: https://github.com/beurtschipper/Depix/pull/83

Cheers!

Comment: @tera98
I don't know if you had time to try the above,
but if it solved your problem I would appreciate if you could accept my answer.
Thx!